# Save workbook in user specified path

Tags: excel, vba

I have below code where I copy all the sheets other than first sheet from Workbook A ( macro file ) to Workbook B ( normal xlsx). I'm able to perform the process successfully . However , I need to handle a scenario when the user clicks cancel in save dialog window. I want a message popping up to user stating " You have clicked on cancel , so the file hasn't saved . retry again " and there should be no workbook opening or saving elsewhere.

Right now when I click on cancel a workbook named TRUE.xlsx is getting saved.

```
    Dim NewWkb As Workbook
    Dim xWkb As Workbook
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim varResult As Variant

    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set xWkb = ThisWorkbook
    Set NewWkb = Workbooks.Add

    For x = 2 To xWkb.Worksheets.count
        xWkb.Worksheets(x).copy after:=NewWkb.Worksheets(NewWkb.Worksheets.count)
    Next x

    NewWkb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Delete
    NewWkb.Worksheets(1).Activate

    NewWkb.SaveAs varResult = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
    fileFilter:="Text Files (*.xlsx), *.xls")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first get the filename into your variable `varResult` and then use that to specify the destination for `.SaveAs`:

```
Dim varResult As Variant

c= Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Text Files (*.xlsx), *.xls")

'check if user has pressed cancel
If VarType(varResult) = vbBoolean And varResult = False Then
    Exit Sub
End If

NewWkb.SaveAs varResult
```

Additionally I recommend to check if the user has pressed the <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button.